# Set a notification before a date

Tags: java, android

I want to schedule a notification according to a date (the date is `PostScheduledDate`) and the notification will be before the `PostScheduledDate` and the amount of time of `before` is 1 min in my code.

I tried this:

```
//here am converting the postScheduledDate to milliseconds
Long postScheduledLong = postScheduledDate.getTime();

// and here converting system time to millisecond
Long systemsCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

// and here am getting the difference between system time and postscheduled time
Long differneceToAdd =  systemsCurrentTime - postScheduledLong;

// here am converting that difference to int so that i can put the int value  to my method 
int delayInt = differneceToAdd.intValue();

// here am subtracting that difference of time by 1 min so that I can 
// show the notification before the scheduled time of post 
int oneminuteBefore  =  delayInt - 60000;

// this is my method which takes the amount of difference in integer form 
// and add that amount of time to the system's time,
//  then on  added time it shows the notification  
scheduleNotification(getNotification("10 second delay"), oneminuteBefore);
```

And here is my method for showing the notification:

```
private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // here am adding that difference of time for scheduling notification 
    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay; 
    Log.v("ReminderTime  = "+futureInMillis, "");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}
```

I don't know why I am not getting the notification back but I know that my method is working fine cause I tried with some hardcodes  for  `1min` , `30sec` etc.

Comment: what is NotificationPublisher ?

Comment: its class which reacts as a receiver @logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out really simple i tried something like this

```
 String[] postTypeArray = new String[]{"1 hour Before", "6 hour Before", "1 Day Before"};


        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title("Set Reminder")
                .items(postTypeArray)
                .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {

                        if (which == 0) {

                       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                       cal.setTime(postScheduledDate);
                       cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
                       Long oneHourBack = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                       scheduleNotification(getNotification( dateStr ,""+titleStr), oneHourBack);

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Reminder has been setted for " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (which == 1) {

                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            cal.setTime(postScheduledDate);
                            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
                            Long oneHourBack = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                            scheduleNotification(getNotification( dateStr ,""+titleStr), oneHourBack);

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Reminder has been setted for " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if ( which == 2){
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            cal.setTime(postScheduledDate);
                            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
                            Long oneHourBack = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                            scheduleNotification(getNotification( dateStr ,""+titleStr), oneHourBack);

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Reminder has been setted for " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                })
                .show();
```

here `MaterialDialog` is  a dialog builder assume it an listView with  different options for selecting the time for notification